# Why I get an error when I try to execute a command remotely?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, quoting

I have a problem about execute command remotely via SSH. I am trying below.

```
ssh xx.xx.xx.xx "psql -U qradar -c "select count(id) from offense_view where to_timestamp(start_time/1000) > NOW() - interval '180 minutes'"
```

It gives an error like:

> ```
> Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "180"
> LINE 1: ... to_timestamp(start_time/1000) > NOW() - interval 180 minute...
> ```

Comment: _"an error like"_ is not very specific.  Copy and paste the exact error message.  Although on the face of it this is not a programming related question, so off-topic on SO.  The required argument to `to_timestamp` is a string; what you are passing is not a string.   Perhaps `to_timestamp(start_time) / 1000 > NOW() ... ` https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_timestamp.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using double quotes to delimit the argument to `ssh` and also the argument to `psql` inside the command. This is causing your strings to be parsed incorrectly. You're also missing the ending double quote for the `psql` command.

Nesting quotes is tricky in shell, and it's even harder when you're using `ssh`. It's easier if you use a here-doc.

```
ssh xx.xx.xx.xx <<EOF
psql -U qradar -c "select count(id) from offense_view where to_timestamp(start_time/1000) > NOW() - interval '180 minutes'"
EOF
```

Comment: Hey! It works thank you. One more question, I want to use that command in a python script, are there any one line version of this?

Comment: You can use `subprocess.Popen([["ssh", "x.x.x.x"], stdin=PIPE)` and then use `Popen.communicate()` to write the `psql` command to the pipe.